# Can you make a vector of functions with parameters?

Tags: c++, vector

Is it possible to create a vector that has functions pushed back?
I've tried doing something with pointers, but it only works with functions without parameters.

For example,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printInt();

int main()
{
    vector<void (*)()> functionStack;

    functionStack.push_back(printInt);

    (*functionStack[0])();
}

void printInt()
{
    cout << "function works!" << 123 << endl;
}
```

That works, but not what I need.
The correct version of that would be a function that has parameters: `void printInt(int a)` and you could call it with different values like `4` or `-1` but from the vector `functionStack`.

It's probably more complex if the functions in the vector are with different parameters, so let's assume that every function has the same type and amount of parameters.

Comment: What have you tried w.r.t. functions w/ arguments? It looks like you're basically there.

Comment: Have you tried `vector<void (*)(int)> functionStack;` and, correspondingly, elsewhere, `void printInt(int a);`?

Comment: `printStr` in the question is just a typo I assume?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
void (*)()
```

is a function pointer taking *no* arguments. So change it to take the desired argument.

```
void (*)(int)
```

Like so:

```
void printInt(int x)
{
    cout << "function works!" << x << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<void (*)(int)> functionStack;

    functionStack.push_back(printInt);

    (*functionStack[0])(123);
}
```

You are correct in saying the functions must have the same type and number of parameters for this to be valid.

Comment: usually I am the one complaining about `std::function` when there is no need to... +1

Comment: @acraig5075 Thanks! I'd be pretty interested to see how this is performed with different type and number of parameters, but as there's no immediate need I'll leave it for another day.

Answer (score 2):

You basically had it already.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printInt(int a);

int main()
{
    // Just needed the parameter type
    vector<void (*)(int)> functionStack;

    // Note that I removed the () from after the function
    // This is how we get the function pointer; the () attempts to
    // invoke the function
    functionStack.push_back(printInt);

    (*functionStack[0])(42);
}

void printInt(int a)
{
    cout << "function works! " << a << endl;
}
```

This is also a situation where `std::function` might be beneficial as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printInt(int a);

int main()
{
    // Similar syntax, std::function allows more flexibility at a 
    // lines of assembly generated cost. But it's an up-front cost
    vector<std::function<void(int)>> functionStack;

    functionStack.push_back(printInt);

    // I don't have to de-reference a pointer anymore
    functionStack[0](42);
}

void printInt(int a)
{
    cout << "function works! " << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth it's not necessary to dereference the function pointer either.

Comment: Good to know. I don't mess with raw function pointers a lot. Just messy to me given that lambdas exist.

Comment: @sweenish Thanks, I will take a look at `std::function`.